# Is there any math software that works like music composing app, Staffpad?

Tags: math-software

Doing math with pen and paper is pretty inefficient. Latex and stuffs also arent' intuitive enough. Right?

Ex1. when you draw the same triangles and circles again and again trying to solve geometry problem.

Ex2. copy-writing almost all of the last equation just to change one term.

---

We need this for maths. "Introducing StaffPad"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_PgKyqE3RU

If you still don't get the sense. Here is my metaphor.

- Notepad        >>>   Sublime Text
- pen and paper  >>>   what I'm talking about

Here are basically-prefered functions:

- loop (Ex. writing 1 to 100, writing Jacobian Determinant etc.)
- change hand-written expression to Latex-like
- real time proof-check
- copy, paste, undo, redo

---

This got me to the question in the Title.
So my questions are,

1. Is there this kind of software out there yet? If not, when is it going to be?
2. What do you call the app that I'm talking about, generally? Math OCR APP? Math notation APP?
3. How do mathematicians do maths now? Do they still use pen and paper?(I know they use computer sometimes. I mean the theory part when they define stuffs)

---

The closest things I could find are,
"mathpix"
and
"inftyreader"

Hope this will come to existence soon. T T

Comment: Mathematica allows for symbolic operations

Comment: GeoGebra is a great piece of software. It has an app to work with tablets. It makes very nice graphs, it does also some basic CAS, a script language and can export in LaTeX, in PS, in PDF. It is free as in "free speech" and it exists for almost any OS, including Linux. It has a large community and a lot of support.